# Analog fuction to xaxis in Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I´m looking for any similar function to  `axis.` using  `numpy array`
I´m trying to generate subplots and I set different parameters to generate three plots.
Here the package that I´m using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import (AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator)
```

The subplot shares the x-axis; this axis has a range of 0 to 1200. So, my goal is to split in 50 (0; 50; 100;... ;1200).
For this purpose I´m using the function:

```
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
```

However, this gives me this error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

I understand partially the issue, so I search for a similar function in `numpy array`
to do that.
Perhaps this function could be work:

```
numpy.apply_along_axis()
```

However, I can´t fix the issue yet.
Here is the complete script if anyone needs it.

```
# Set the style of the plot
plt.style.use("seaborn")
# Set the data for each method (SLAC, FEL and MEME)
data_SLAC = pd.read_csv("S_SLAC.csv")
dN_SLAC = data_SLAC["dN"]
dS_SLAC = data_SLAC["dS"]
Omega_SLAC = data_SLAC["P [dN/dS > 1]"]

data_FEL = pd.read_csv("S_FEL.csv")
dN_FEL = data_FEL["beta"]
dS_FEL = data_FEL["alpha"]
Omega_FEL = data_FEL["omega"]

data_MEME = pd.read_csv("S_MEME.csv")
dN_MEME = data_MEME["&beta"]
dS_MEME = data_MEME["&alpha"]
Omega_MEME_positive = data_MEME["&beta+"]
Omega_MEME_neutral = data_MEME["&beta-"]
# Set the parameters of the subplot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1, sharex=True, sharey=False, figsize=(16,5))
#ax.plot(dN, label="dN")
#ax.plot(dS, label="dS")
axs[0].plot(Omega_SLAC, label="dN/dS > 1")
axs[1].plot(Omega_FEL, label="dN/dS > 1")
axs[2].plot(Omega_MEME_positive, label="dN/dS > 1")

#### HERE THE LINE OF THE POST!

# Set the range of values in x-axis
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
# Set title of each subplot
axs.set_title("Selection Score for each Method")
# Fix the distribution of each plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot()
```

Well, I´m looking for any suggestion to fix the issue. Any comment or help is welcome!
Thank!

Comment: `axs` is an array of `Axes`.  I expect individual elements of that array will have a `xaxis` attribute, but the array, as a whole, does not.  Unless there's some utility in `matplotlib`, I think you'll have apply the `set` to each Axes individually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you give me a simple example of using the set with my example? Only to understand your idea.

Comment: `for ax in axs: ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the script:

```
for ax in axs:
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(50))
```